# iPhone demo from mockups - no data connection

Tags: iphone, html, mobile, ios5, responsive-design

I've mocked up screenshots for an iPhone app, and I'd like to create a demo that will run on several "internal" iPhone 4 and 4S's. The demo will simply allow menus to move the user between screens and provide lifelike UISwitches, etc. All very basic with no underlying functionality.

Most importantly, **the demo will need to run without any data connection**.

Can I do this in a browser relying on HTML5 Application cache, or will I need to develop a native app?

Any other tips to complete this project in the easiest way possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to build all the views using the new Storyboarding functionality in the latest version of Xcode. That will let you construct your app more-or-less entirely using drag and drop without writing any code.

The great advantage of this is that once you're happy with the mockup you can basically just give it to a developer and they can turn it into the real app by writing the code behind the controls.

Try downloading Xcode and creating a new Storyboard-based project and see how you get on.

The only catch is that whilst you can run your app in the simulator for free, you will need a developer licence to install it on your phones, which means forking out $99.

There are some wireframing solutions that don't require a developer licence and will build the mockup app using HTML. If you'd prefer that approach, check out Prototypes on the Mac App Store:

http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/prototypes/id430812258?mt=12

Comment: Is there anything like prototypes that will work offline? Looks like prototypes needs a data connection.

Comment: Prototypes just spits out HTML, so you could copy all the files onto a server and set up an html manifest file to cache the resources so it can function offline. That's always a bit risky though as iOS might decide to flush the cache and leave you in trouble. Another option would be to use PhoneGap to wrap up the HTML into an app, with the files hosted locally in the application bundle. The problem there is that to install your PhoneGap app on a device you'd need to have a developer licence, in which case you may as well just go the Storyboard route instead.

Comment: Yet another option would be to use something like http://lesscode.co.nz/interface or http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imockups-for-ipad/id364885913?mt=8, which are wireframing tools that run directly on the device and let you create offline mockups using real iOS controls. I've not really used either of them though so I can't vouch for how good the output is.

Comment: Makes sense. Looks like it's time to wrap my head around XCode and deploy the demo using TestFlight. Thanks!